Android Auto implementation for my radio-app
I'm searching for someone who can help me out with Android Auto implementation of my radio-app. Who can help me out pls?
I found out that there are 2 possible solutions:

One via androidx.car.app.CarAppService - in this solution I'm able to make a gridTemplate with items via onGetTemplate(). I can play and pause the stream, but the media player in Android Auto isn't filled.
One via android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService. In this solution the onGetRoot is not called ;-(

What solution should I follow for a radio-app? 1 or 2.
In solution 2 (the way to go I think) I've this in my Manifest:
<service
     android:name=".MyService"
     android:enabled="true"
     android:exported="true"
     android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback">
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="androidx.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver" />
                <action android:name="androidx.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
     </intent-filter>
</service>

And this is myService:
class MyService : MediaBrowserService(), Player.Listener, OnAudioFocusChangeListener {

 override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder {

        Log.i(TAG, "stationAPP: onBind()")

        return binder

    }

    override fun onGetRoot(p0: String, p1: Int, p2: Bundle?): BrowserRoot? {

        TODO("Not yet implemented")

        println("XXXXX")

    }

override fun onLoadChildren(p0: String, p1: Result<MutableList<MediaBrowser.MediaItem>>) {

    TODO("Not yet implemented")

    println("YYYYY")

    }

}

MyService is running nice and is in fact my own media player. It works great on a mobile, but in Android Auto I don't see anything.

Have you checked out the developer documentation for media apps on Android Auto? https://developer.android.com/training/cars/media and https://developer.android.com/training/cars/media/auto

I added some more information in the question. I used both links, but somehow I can't figure out what approach I should use.

For a radio app, you should use the second option, a MediaBrowserService. For Android Auto, make sure you also make the manifest changes from https://developer.android.com/training/cars/media/auto#manifest-car-app. Also, you'll need to implement the MediaBrowserService methods for Android Auto to be able to properly connect and display your content. You can also reference https://github.com/android/uamp as a sample. https://github.com/android/uamp/blob/main/common/src/main/java/com/example/android/uamp/media/MusicService.kt is the MediaBrowserService implementation.
